# Connecting Windows 10 IoT Core Pi to corporate domain WiFi

Tags: networking, wifi, windows-iot

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Win IoT core and I'm attempting to connect it via WiFi to a corporate network.  The interface options appear to only accept a psk to join a WiFi network.  Is there a way to provide domain credentials to join a WiFi network? TIA

Comment: You mean the WiFi is authenticated using some kind of RADIUS server? I would assume you can find more details there but not sure how to set that up on the IoT

Comment: Possible solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=56641) or [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=249654).

Comment: @goobering The question asks about Windows, not Linux.

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I haven't tested it myself, but you could try this: https://www.gittprogram.com/question/3292875_connecting-w10-iot-o-wpa2-peap-wifi-network.html

Comment: Thanks Moshe.  The info in the link that you provided was the solution for us.  We are now working on having the script run when the Pi boots up and encrypting the script so the username and password are not saved in clear text - there are loads of example online on how to do this :).  Thanks again.